# Can't change default password in Kali-linux

Tags: terminal, freeze, kali-linux

I always log into Kali-linux using the default password. When I try to change it in the terminal using `sudo passwd kali`, it prompts me to type new password. When try to type new password it just I can't type anything. I can still use the mouse though so I can't quite figure out the problem. (I use raspberry pi 4.)

Comment: Did it not ask you for the password when you set it up?  Kali and Ubuntu both ask for user name and password.  Try this article:   https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-kali-linux-root-password#:~:text=Type%20passwd%20command%20and%20enter,the%20password%20reset%20was%20successful.

Comment: And if using a live session you can't change it obviously.

Comment: Yes , article shows you how to get started to change the password.  SO much easier to do this at setup.

Comment: If you are not too far along, you can always just reinstall Kali.   Set the password during installation. I have done that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Use the Kali Linux Recovery Mode

1. Press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while powering off your Raspberry Pi.
2. While holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, power on your Raspberry Pi.
3. Then a Kali Linux boot menu should open. Choose “Recovery Mode” from the menu.
4. Next, you should see the Kali Linux recovery menu, select the option: “Change root password.”
5. Enter your new password twice
6. Reboot

Comment: The original poster’s issue is when they run a very standard `sudo passwd kali` (which is the way passwords typically get changed in the terminal) the keyboard appears to do nothing.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Nice edit btw, I forgot about **kbd** tags!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Agreed. And _why I didn't suggest_ using `passwd`, instead I offerred a lower level solution which shouldn't be affected by Kali linux install. Which makes me wonder if those folks that down voted is due to not understanding my solution??!! It may not be _the perfect answer_ inside Kali, but its a legit answer based on info provided. And may get @Core747 out of their bind